# Create a 12 months array from few months given

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this PHP array:

```
array(
  [1528840800] => 50  // 12 June 2018 22:00:00
  [1531173600] => 37  // 9 July 2018 22:00:00
  [1540940400] => 44  // 30 October 2018 23:00:00
  [1543532400] => 9   // 29 November 2018 23:00:00
)
```

How can i get a full 12 months array where remaining months value are zero?

```
  array(
  [01]         => 0
  [02]         => 0
  [03]         => 0
  [04]         => 0
  [05]         => 0
  [1528840800] => 50  // 12 June 2018 22:00:00
  [1531173600] => 37  // 9 July 2018 22:00:00
  [08]         => 0
  [09]         => 0
  [1540940400] => 44  // 30 October 2018 23:00:00
  [1543532400] => 9   // 29 November 2018 23:00:00
  [12]         => 0
```

)

This not works property on the second value..

```
for ($i=1;$i<13;$i++) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (date('m',$key)===sprintf('%02d', $i)) {
      $fullmonths[date('d/m/Y',$key)] = $value;
      break;
    }else{
      $fullmonths['XXXX/'.sprintf('%02d', $i).'/2018]=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: what is not worlking ? - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/047b490446f4b3eef6d283ed81efb2aad183bd6d

Comment: @splash58 July, October and November are duplicated, see results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some changes to skip to the next month correctly. You can break or continue a loop on any level. If set `continue 2` you starts next itteration of the for loop. Else, you will fill default value

```
for ($i=1;$i<13;$i++) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (date('m',$key) === sprintf('%02d', $i)) {
      $fullmonths[date('d/m/Y',$key)] = $value;
      // If found skip to next month
      continue 2;
    }
  }
  $fullmonths['XX/'.sprintf('%02d', $i).'/2018'] = 0;  
}
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62a657fc47a8070d2b703a1af7c1407aa637edab)

Answer (score 1):

Kind of what you were already doing.
If you want to re:use the original array, just change `$months` to `$array`.

```
$array = [
  "1528840800" => 50,
  "1531173600" => 37,
  "1540940400" => 44,
  "1543532400" => 9
];
$months = [];

for ($i=1;$i <= 12;$i++) {
    foreach($array as $time => $value) {
        $date = date("n", $time);
        if ($date == $i) {
            $months[$time] = $value;break;
        } else {
            $months[$i] = 0;
        }

    }
}

var_dump($months);
```

If you need Zero padding to the months, simply add `str_pad()` to the `[$i]`, like these:

```
[str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using `STR_PAD_LEFT` and update the key.

```
$mainArray=array();
$output = array('1528840800' => '50', '1531173600' => '37', '1540940400' => '44', '1543532400' => '9');

for ($i=1; $i <= 12; $i++) 
{   
  $value = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $mainArray[$value] = 0;  //set Everykey to Zero
}

foreach ($output as $key => $value) 
{
  $joy = gmdate("m", $key);
  $mainArray[$key]=$value; //update the key 
  unset($mainArray[$joy]); 
}
```